# WinForms disable double clicks and accept all mouse clicks?

Tags: c#, winforms, double-click

How do you get all clicks to go through the event? I noticed if you click too fast it thinks you are double clicking and doesn't send the clicks to the event handler. Is there a way to get all the clicks?

Comment: Use the mousedown event instead.

Comment: @RussellTroywest I think that [MouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick%28VS.80%29.aspx) event would be better. Because of raising order.

Comment: @Michael: According to MSDN "Two single clicks that occur close enough in time, as determined by the mouse settings of the user's operating system, will generate a MouseDoubleClick event instead of the second MouseClick event." - Which is what High is seeing.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to turn off double-click events but you'll need to document the specific control you are using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not that sure why this question got a bounty, the accepted answer ought to be already pretty close to a solution.  Except that you ought to use MouseUp instead of MouseDown, your user typically expects a click action to take effect when he releases the button.  Which provides the back-out "oops, didn't mean to click it, move the mouse so it gets ignored" option.

Nevertheless, for the built-in Winforms controls, like PictureBox, this is configurable with the Control.SetStyle() method.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyPictureBox : PictureBox {
    public MyPictureBox() {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, false);
    }
}
```

Do beware however that this won't work for the .NET classes that wrap an existing native Windows control.  Like TextBox, ListBox, TreeView, etc.  The underlying configuration for that is the [WNDCLASSEX.style member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), CS_DBLCLKS style flag.  The code that sets that style flag is baked into Windows and cannot be changed.  You'd need different kind of surgery to turn a double-click back into a single click.  You can do so by overriding the WndProc() method, I'll give an example for TextBox:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyTextBox : TextBox {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Change WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK to WM_LBUTTONCLICK
        if (m.Msg == 0x203) m.Msg = 0x201;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Just change the class name if you want to do it for other controls.  Commandeering Winforms to make it work the way you want never takes much code, just Petzold :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the controls MouseDown event instead of the Click event. MouseDown will be called every single time the mouse is "pressed" on that control. Click may not get called if the system thinks it was a double click. A DoubleClick event would be raised instead.

Answer (score -2):

I think you want to count all click.
If you want to count click then set one counter variable and increase it in click event.
May be this help to you....

Comment: Do that yourself and click it really fast 10 times. You will get a number less than 10. I want all 10 of those clicks.