# Button Click Event doesn't fire when clicking same button twice in a row

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

So, a weird one... I have a very simple form with 10 buttons on it.  Each as a number on it 0-9.  They all have the same `Click Event Handler` which is shown below.

If I click, say, 4 different buttons in a row it feels fluid and works as expected.
However, if I click the same button(number) twice in a row there is a NOTICEABLE delay on the second click.  I can't for the life of me figure out why....

```
void uxNumberClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int num = Convert.ToInt32(((GradientButton)sender).Text);

  if (this.uxPIN.Text.Length < 4)
    uxPIN.Text += num;    
  else
    SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused on this.  Are you saying that you click the same button as if you are double clicking it, or are you clicking it and then pausing then clicking again?

Comment: The second one...maybe it is getting confused though and thinking I'm double clicking...  For example, if I enter 8540 I can click pretty much as fast as I can and it registers all 4 clicks.  If I enter 0221 though, on the second 2 it doesn't register(click event doesn't fire) and I end up waiting a split second and clicking it again.

Comment: I'm an idiot...you inadvertently gave me an answer.  The Double Click Event is firing.  Soooo, now the real question is how to suppress that.

Comment: you could just call the single click handler from the double click handler

Comment: true...looks like I could also use a different event, like `Mouse_Down`...see here -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561585/winforms-disable-double-clicks-and-accept-all-mouse-clicks

Comment: Yes, that is also a method to do this.  It is a matter of how you'd like to perform this and allow for later expansion.  Mouse_Down is useful for coding that will never change and never have a need for double click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our comments, Mouse_Down would look something like this:

```
private void uxNumber_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(((GradientButton)sender).Text);

        if (this.uxPIN.Text.Length < 4)
            uxPIN.Text += num;    
        else
        SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
    }

}
```