# Visual Studio 2015 C# Slow Click with PictureBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, click, picturebox

I am using a PictureBox to cycle through a set of images on my program.  When I click the image, the picture changes.  When I click multiple times, sometimes it does not change.  I assume this is because my clicks are being registered as a double-click, instead of a single-click?

If so, how can I "disable" double-click to enable fast scrolling through the images?

Answer (score 1):

3 Options:

1. (Lengthy Resolution) Disable all double clicks and have the application register all clicks as a single click: [WinForms disable double clicks and accept all mouse clicks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561585/winforms-disable-double-clicks-and-accept-all-mouse-clicks)
2. (Not recommended...repetitive) Make the event handler for DoubleClick perform the same function as your onClick.
3. (Preferred/Probably Easiest) Instead of your onClick making the pictures change....make the MouseDown/MouseUp event handler on the pictureBox process your picture change request.

Comment: For option 2 you could instead subclass the Picturebox control and override OnMouseClick to handle all double click's in a single place.