# Fast Clicking TreeView's Checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

The problem is when I click the TreeView's CheckBox so fast (double clicking), it won't run the second AfterCheck (event is not working). Then I click again the same CheckBox, then it will run.

In summary, AfterCheck or BeforeCheck events do not work on very fast CheckBox clickings. They don't work on second click, they work on third click.

How can I fix that or prevent that?

Comment: Thinking loud without [MCVE]: the first click generate click event normally, but second is probably recognized as a double click (try to subscribe to that event and check), which will prevent normal click event from being called. If it's so, then you can try to [disable double click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664613/1997232) or handle it and simply toggle checkbox in event handler.

Comment: Actually in the third click, it recognized as a double click. So my second click is completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it's about mouse click speed. I increase double click speed to fastest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).