# Prevent button to be double-clicked in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an (`async`) operation, which gets executed when a `Button` is clicked. Indeed, I don't want to execute that code (for example opening a `ContentDialog`) when the button is double-clicked.

My current approach is to increment a variable when the method is entered and decrement it when the method is leaved.

```
int locker = 0;

private async void HandleDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if(locker > 0) return;
    locker++;

    ContentDialog editConfirmationDialog = new ContentDialog {
        Title = "a",
        Content = "b",
        PrimaryButtonText = "c",
    };


    ContentDialogResult result = await editConfirmationDialog.ShowAsync();
    locker--;
}
```

Unfortunately, there are a lot of buttons which needed to be protected that way and I don't want to repeat myself all the time with this `locker`-code. Therefore I'm looking for a way to extract this behaviour in a subclass of `Button`, in a property or something reusable.

Is there any way to do this in UWP?

Comment: Why not just disable the button on the first click then re-enable it after your method is finished executing?

Comment: But it's basically the same problem. I have to copy-paste this code in every single `Click`-handler.

Comment: This approach with a variable will hurt you when for some reason you'll have to attach two or more handlers attached to the very same button. It's better to guard inside actual process than in the code that orchestrates it (it your case, inside the dialog). This pattern is called [Balking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balking_pattern) and unfortunately, it basically needs an auxiliary variable.

Comment: @DasElias Yep. You have to put the same logic in each event handler method as each event handler is unique to the button which fires it. Or you can attach the same event to each button and do the same disable/enable in the method but choose different logic for the rest of the method based on the button firing the event.

Comment: I agree that my approach with the variable is problematic. When there are two or even more handlers in a class, this would get confusing quickly. Nevertheless, I hoped there would be a solution like [this one for WPF](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/disable-button-double-click-in-wpf-application). But if there are no better approaches, I will go with `IsEnabled`, even though I wonder how this is handled in bigger applications.

Comment: There is a way to [disable the standard double click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664613/2330053), but this doesn't help with clicking the button slowly while the async operation is still running.  The only good way to do that is to disable, then re-enable again when done.  There's no way to make that universal, though, as every button is going to do something different, and there's no way to know when that "thing" is done for each different button...

Comment: This seems to go in the right direction and would be what I'm looking for. Nevertheless, this solution is for WinForms and I don't see how to use that with UWP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have to add code in every method that you want to do this. You can however do it a bit smarter by creating a class for this.

Something like this:

```
public class DoubleClickPreventer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Button _button;

    public DoubleClickPreventer(object sender)
    {
        _button = (Button)sender;
        _button.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _button.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

That code allows you to add minimal code to your callbacks:

```
private async void HandleDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    using (var buttonLock = new DoubleClickPreventer(sender))
    {

        ContentDialog editConfirmationDialog = new ContentDialog {
            Title = "a",
            Content = "b",
            PrimaryButtonText = "c",
        };


        ContentDialogResult result = await editConfirmationDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

The great thing is that the button with also get enabled if something goes wrong (an exception is thrown).

Comment: This is as much, if not more, work for each handler than just setting enabled to true at the start and false at the end.  Exceptions aren't really an issue since an unhandled exception is tearing down the application, so it doesn't matter if the button is enabled or disabled at that point.

Comment: Even though there's a little bit of overhead, I think I will go with that solution, since the code in the handlers stays clear and you mentioned an approach which I would never have thought of. A little improvement to your answer, it's `_button.IsEnabled` and not `_button.Enabled` in UWP.

Comment: @Servy: You get no unhandled exceptions with the global exception handlers.

Comment: @jgauffin Which should only really be logging and closing out of the program, not ignoring the exceptions and trying to keep the existing UI running.  If you're just swallowing any exceptions that happen all sorts of bad things will happen.  You can't possibly code everything you write to work possibly if arbitrary exceptions happen anywhere and don't end the program.

Comment: You do know that we are talking about desktop applications? Not crashing them, but aborting the current execution flow (as the global exception handler does) doesn't impact the application in the way that you describe. If you think that it does, you need to be more specific and not generalize.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your own button you can't (easily) change the existing `Click` event handlers to do what you want, but if you're willing to make your own event for handlers that disable the button while running that's easy enough.

```
public class ButtonThatDisablesWhileClickHandlerIsRunning : Button //TODO consider renaming
{
    public event Func<ButtonThatDisablesWhileClickHandlerIsRunning, Task> ClickThatDisablesWhileRunning;

    protected override async void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        this.Enabled = false;
        foreach(Delegate handler in ClickThatDisablesWhileRunning?.GetInvocationList())
        {
            await ((Func<ButtonThatDisablesWhileClickHandlerIsRunning, Task>)handler).Invoke(this);
        }
        this.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

For this approach the existing `Click` event won't work because the delegate doesn't return the `Task` to let this control know when the handlers have finished.

If you *really* wanted to use the `Click` event, then you'd need to make your own `SynchronizationContext`, override the Winform's current sync context, call the click event handlers, then forward all post/send requests form that custom sync context to the winforms sync context until there are no pending continuations.  That's not nearly as easy, and is also not infallible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question was tagged with UWP, so the code wouldn't work on my platform. Nevertheless, I got the idea to be able to implement this in UWP.